# Pandas : vectorized operations on maximum values per row

Tags: python, pandas, max, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following pandas dataframe `df`:

```
index        A    B    C
    1        1    2    3
    2        9    5    4
    3        7    12   8
    ...      ...  ...  ...
```

I want the maximum value of each row to remain unchanged, and all the other values to become `-1`. The output would thus look like this :

```
index        A    B    C
    1       -1   -1    3
    2        9   -1   -1
    3       -1    12  -1
    ...      ...  ...  ...
```

By using `df.max(axis = 1)`, I get a pandas `Series` with the maximum values per row. However, I'm not sure how to use these maximums optimally to create the result I need. I'm looking for a vectorized, fast implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
>>> df.where(df.eq(df.max(1), 0), -1)
       A   B  C
index          
1     -1  -1  3
2      9  -1 -1
3     -1  12 -1
```

Here `df.eq(df.max(1), 0)` is a boolean DataFrame marking the row maximums; True values (the maximums) are left untouched whereas False values become -1. You can also use a Series or another DataFrame instead of a scalar if you like.

The operation can also be done inplace (by passing `inplace=True`).

Comment: this is the neater answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create boolean `mask` by comparing by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) by rows, then apply inverted `mask`:

```
print df
       A   B  C
index          
1      1   2  3
2      9   5  4
3      7  12  8

print df.max(axis=1)
index
1     3
2     9
3    12
dtype: int64

mask = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
print mask
           A      B      C
index                     
1      False  False   True
2       True  False  False
3      False   True  False

df[~mask] = -1
print df
       A   B  C
index          
1     -1  -1  3
2      9  -1 -1
3     -1  12 -1
```

All together:

```
df[~df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)] = -1
print df
       A   B  C
index          
1     -1  -1  3
2      9  -1 -1
3     -1  12 -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an new dataframe the same size of `df` consisting of -1 for each value.  Then use `enumerate` to get the *first* max value in a given row, using integer getting/setting of a scalar (`iat`).

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(-np.ones(df.shape), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

for row, col in enumerate(np.argmax(df.values, axis=1)):
    df2.iat[row, col] = df.iat[row, col]

>>> df2
   0   1  2
0 -1  -1  3
1  9  -1 -1
2 -1  12 -1
```

**Timings**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 10000))

%%timeit
df2 = pd.DataFrame(-np.ones(df.shape))
for row, col in enumerate(np.argmax(df.values, axis=1)):
    df2.iat[row, col] = df.iat[row, col]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.19 s per loop

%timeit df.where(df.eq(df.max(1), 0), -1)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.27 s per loop

# Using inplace=True
%timeit df.where(df.eq(df.max(1), 0), -1, inplace=True)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.58 s per loop

%timeit df[~df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)] = -1
1 loops, best of 3: 5.65 s per loop
```

Comment: I think you lost index and columns of `DataFrame`, but if OP dont need it, your answer win.

Comment: Yes, I never set them to begin with. I've edited construction of `df2` above.

Comment: Also note that `df.where(df.eq(df.max(1), 0), -1)` returns a *new* DataFrame; the other two methods modify the existing DataFrame. On my machine, passing `inplace=True` makes using `where` a little faster (only a little though).

Comment: (Also, using `np.argmax(df.values, axis=1)` will just get the index of the *first* maximum value in each row, so the other maximum values will become -1. This may or may not be what the OP wants, but is probably worth flagging up.)

Comment: Yes, that's one of the reasons it is much faster.  I took that liberty given the OP's request for speed and lack of details requiring duplicate max values on a given row.

Comment: Though not specified in the question, I do need to keep all the maximal values per row. Hence, `np.argmax` won't do the trick in this case.